What is the difference between PL SQL CTE and cache Lazy table in spark
When a spark sql "CACHE TABLE AS SELECT * FROM TABLE" is cached and can be used in reduced scanning of the original files in future queries.
And
A CTE in sql does the same when a same subquery is used in a query instead of fetching output for the same subquery.
My understanding is CTE does it every time when the query is run,
However cache table has this data until the cluster is terminated?
spark sql:
cache lazy table
as
select * from abc.demo_tbl;
With abc as
(select * from abc.demo_tbl)
select * from abc;
Both does the same in back end ?
